# How to use *ngFor to create repeating checkbox input fields in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to create multiple checkbox fields using ngFor. I have an array which consists of project ids, names and types.
So, now I am trying to create multiple input checkbox fields according to the number of projects that I have.

The ng-serve works fine and shows no error but the browser shows the error on [(ngModel)] at the frontend.

The code that I have been trying with is below:
Here is the definition of `projectsList` array:

```
    let loggedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedInfo'));
        this.commonService.getProjectList(loggedData.value).then((response)=>{
            this.allProjectList = response;
            console.log('this.allProjectList',response);
            var checkedItems = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(response).length; i++) {
              this.projectsList.push({id: response[i].id, projectName: response[i].projectName, projectNumber: response[i].projectNumber})
            }
        });
```

And here is the template part in html:

```
    <tr *ngFor="let cl of projectsList; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i"><td>
                                     <div style="width:150"><font style="font-size: 8pt;">{{cl.projectName}} - {{cl.projectNumber}}</font></div>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                     <input class="form-check-input " type="checkbox" value="false" name="cl.projectNumber" [(ngModel)]="accountLoginPrivilegeModel.activeSubaccountView[cl.projectNumber]">
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                     <input class="form-check-input " type="checkbox" name="cl.projectNumber" [(ngModel)]="accountLoginPrivilegeModel.activeSubaccountTransfer[cl.projectNumber]">
                                  </td>
                               </tr>
```

And here is the error that I am getting at [(ngModel)].
[image]

Any help would be more than appreciable.

Comment: either `accountLoginPrivilegeModel.activeSubaccountView` or `accountLoginPrivilegeModel.activeSubaccountTransfer` is undefined on one or several of items

Comment: @Andrei could you please elaborate more? I am trying to understand your comment. As far as I know, the value inside the large brackets like [cl.projectNumber] is the culprit but have no idea how to resolve it.

Comment: Is says in the error it is in LoginprivilegeComponent line 102. So which line would that be?

Comment: @SehaxX The error is related to this line where ngModel is used: `<input class="form-check-input " type="checkbox" value="false" name="cl.projectNumber" [(ngModel)]="accountLoginPrivilegeModel.activeSubaccountView[cl.projectNumber]">`

Comment: is `getProjectList()` http call? If that is so, this behaviour would make sense, since you are binding `ngModels` but you dont have `*ngIf` to check if array already has items

Comment: @tony yah the `getProjectList()` is the function for the api call. This returns the Project data which is then used to build the array called `projectsList`

Comment: @saurav.rox OK, try placing whole `tr` into `<div *ngIf="projectsList.length>0"></div>`

Comment: @tony I get the results in the projectsList. So, is it necessary to check it using ngIf? As far as I know, the main issue is with the [(ngModel)] in the input as commented above.

Comment: @saurav.rox 

The thing here is that `ngModel` is binded immediately on load, binding is based on the infromation you receive via http call,  but you do not have data immediately since you are loading in array information received from http call. You are not using `async pipe` nothing is waiting for data to be received, so you must force it via `ngIf`.

You shoud try it and you should also try removing `ngModels` and see what happens

Comment: @tony Thank you for your clarification. I used the condition to check the array length. But if I remove the [ngModel] then the form data won't be submitted to save it. Without [ngModel] the form data is not available in the component.ts file.

Comment: So does it fire the same error with condition?

Comment: @tony The error is gone after removing [ngModel] but the submitted data is not available in the component.ts file. I am not able to save the form data.

Comment: I mean, with ngModels but plus ngIf condition, does it fire error?

Comment: if it fires error try modifying `accountLoginPrivilegeModel.` to `accountLoginPrivilegeModel?.`

Comment: Yes it does fires error. Tony, could you please just point me on how can I use ngModel in my scenario where it should be generated dynamically with loop index?

Comment: For that I'd have to see how you generate `accountLoginPrivilegeModel` object, error is telling you that `accountLoginPrivilegeModel.activeSubaccountView` or `accountLoginPrivilegeModel.activeSubaccountTransfer` is undefined, you are not posting very relative information. If you are not allowed to, then create example with dummy data in stackblitz

Comment: This is what you are doing with dummy data. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t7k6wr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

If you want to use loop index, just replace `projectNumber` with `i` in html

Comment: @saurav.rox u welcome, sure i'll post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small stackblitz example of what you are trying to do, but with dummy data.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t7k6wr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you Tony for the clear response. Hope it will be helpful for others as well.